# Prevent UITabBar to hide when pushed

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar, pushviewcontroller

First let me tell about my app scenario. **UINavigationController**{relationship}**UIViewControllerMain**{push}**UITabController**{push}**UIViewControllerOne**. Here problem is tab bar hides in **UIViewControllerOne**. How can i make it visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: never mind.. i solved myself. i added one more uinavigation controller between uitabbarcontroller and uiviewcontrollerOne. :)