# UITabBar disappears

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I need to implement a tabbed view without using the UITabBarController.  I created a view and added a UITabBar to it and set the code to dynamically add subviews to the View.  When I add the first subview in willAppear, the tabbar is no longer visible.  I was thinking the new view was covering it up so I shortened the view that gets added in, but then just white space shows at the bottom of the simulator. Below is the code I call from the willAppear of the main controller with the uiTabBar.  I have tried insertSubView, and just addSubView as well and the same thing happens.

```
-(void)loadHomeViewController
{
    if(!self.homeViewController){
        self.homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.homeViewController.view aboveSubview:self.tabBar];
    }

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.homeViewController.view];
}
```

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now to test this suggestion; the view you are adding as subview, instead of shortening it, try setting the attribute that the view has a tabbar at the bottom, I believe it's in the attribute inspector where you do this. Hopefully that works. I remember having read somewhere Apple discourages doing what you are trying to do because of those hassles of presenting views using tabbar, which the UITabBarController would take care of for you.

Comment: is there any reason you dont want to use UITabBarController?]]

Comment: Apparently you aren't suppose to use a UITabBarController inside a navigation controller.

Comment: I don't see and attribute about a tab bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
-(void)loadHomeViewController
{
if(!self.homeViewController){
    self.homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.homeViewController.view belowSubview:self.tabBar];
}
```

}

Comment: This worked.  I didn't realize the below/above were based on Z index, and not referring to y index.  Z index makes more sense.  Ontop of that the bring to front was canceling out whatever I did anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more `UINavigationController` between `UITabBarController` and `UIViewController`. :)

or i think this will helpful for you...
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244816/prevent-uitabbar-to-hide-when-pushed/12244934#comment16413795_12244934) read comment over it

Comment: I'm not using a UITabBarController.  I'm reading all over the place that you are not suppose to use a UINavigationController and a UITabBarController together.