# Hide Tabbar in Landscape without pushing to NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I want to show another view without Tabbar in Landscape. 
So I create a new view and only change the `self.view` and

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

But it doesn´t work for me. Hope someone can help?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244816/prevent-uitabbar-to-hide-when-pushed/12244934#12244934

Comment: then why there is not any up voting for me?

Comment: i solved your problem of 15 point..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this line in your `viewWillAppear:` method of your view for hide `UITabBar`

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

and for set new view as a RootViewController just use below code...

```
YourNewViewController *objView = [[YourNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNewViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objView]; 
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Comment: this line will only hides the icons but not the whole tab bar

Comment: @user1594021 this line hide the tabbar from the view dude first try and then post comment if you have any query..

Comment: @user1594021 first tell me what you want exactly.. bcoz this line hide the tabbar

Comment: @user1594021 you want to display another view as a rootviewController??

Comment: @user1594021 if you want set your new as a root view then use this code.. YourNewViewController *objView = [[YourNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNewViewController" bundle:nil];UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objView];

    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to push navigationController, then try this code :

```
UINavigationController *navAddEvent = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourObg];

        navAddEvent.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;

        [self presentModalViewController:navAddEvent animated:YES];
```

Comment: That would hide the NavigationBar and not the TabBar or am I wrong?

Comment: no... it will hide navigationController's navigation bar. if you dnt want to hide then you can remove that line of code. I used this code to solve the problem like your problem

Comment: how do you got the "old" naviController if you change to normal view again?