# Re-show Tabbar on Root Controller in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've used tabbar controller. When I navigate by push controller, I've hidden tabbar by using method

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

And when back to Main Root controller, its still hidden.
But, I want to re-show tabbar controller on root controller.

I've used

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = FALSE;
```

But not working. So, how can I get this?

Tell me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273563/hide-uitabbar-when-pushed-while-retaining-touch/11273959#11273959

Comment: @MananSheth see my this answer may this help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839038/hide-tabbar-in-landscape-without-pushing-to-navigationcontroller/13839230#13839230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide your tabBar using this

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
```

And if you want to show it again then use viewWillApper

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=NO;
}
```

And if you want to make animation with hide and show tabBar then follow my answer [Stack Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273563/hide-uitabbar-when-pushed-while-retaining-touch/11273959#11273959)